# How to create a shape with one slanted side and rounded corners on the opposite side?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to create this shape in CSS3? How?
I am stuck: http://dabblet.com/gist/2962169

[image: shape]

```css
h1 {
  background-color: #434b82;
  border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean somthing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CyUpZ/)

```
h1 {
    background-color: #434b82;
    border-radius: 20px 0 0 20px;
    width:500px;
    height:40px;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
h1:after{
    position:absolute;
    width: 80px;    
    border-top: 40px solid #434b82;
    margin-left:500px;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    content:"";
}

<h1></h1>​
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to draw this shape on rectangular element.

This trick uses the idea of dividing whole shape in two parts and then draws each part on the background independently.

```
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #434b82, #434b82),
                    linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, #434b82 50%);

  background-position: top right 20px, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 20px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```css
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #434b82, #434b82),
                    linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 50%, #434b82 50%);
  background-position: top right 20px, 100% 100%;
  background-size: 100% 100%, 20px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 30px 0 0 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
    Some Text Here...
</div>
```